# Setting GPU resources when using Dagster

Tags: cloud, gpu, dagster

I found in Dagster's documentation a section on customizing the resource requirements for machines orchestrated by that service, in AWS ECS and over Kubernetes:

```
https://docs.dagster.io/dagster-cloud/deployment/agents/amazon-ecs/configuration-reference#per-deployment-configuration

https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/guides/kubernetes/customizing-your-deployment#per-job-kubernetes-configuration
```

And in both I can set CPU and memory.

Can I also set the available GPU resources for tasks that require those instead? (e.g. [AWS' GPU based EC2 machines](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#Accelerated_Computing) / [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-gpu.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer [is negative as of version 1.4.11 / 0.20.11 (libs)](https://release-1-4-11.dagster.dagster-docs.io/dagster-cloud/deployment/agents/amazon-ecs/configuration-reference#per-deployment-configuration).

The documentation seems to specify only cpu and memory. (In both server_resouces and run_resources. I assume the first is for Dagster itself, and the latter is for the workers)

Furthermore, [looking at the code parsing the run resouces](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster-cloud/blob/1cd14ec75c77ffdd64a4396297dd9208c7597d4f/dagster-cloud/dagster_cloud/workspace/config_schema/ecs.py#L35) only 4 fields are extracted: cpu, memory, ephemeral_storage and repository_credentials. (As of the current release)

Comment: I think this is also related to this -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77027309/why-do-i-need-to-specify-ecs-cluster-name-and-separately-its-cpu-memory-require

Even if I created a cluster on my own with GPU resources, I assume it wouldn't be used, as dagster doesn't use all of the instances in the cluster but only the ones that fit the spec given to it.